# Sending MMS using buttonClick in Android without the UI.Is this possible?

Tags: android, mms

Can i use only a button Click for sending MMS disabling UI?
Is this possible using Intent.ActionSENDTO

Help me!

Regards.

Comment: if you need to unify two accounts go to meta and ask for it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

to send an MMS then use this code snippet:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```

here uri is path of your file. plus you can also define the number on which you want to send this mms